# How to edit DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a .txt file in with this sequence

Lat: -30.0864   30°52′57″S
Lon: -51.2245  51°18′04″W
Distance: 4.8959 km   Meters: 4895.9

All this information should be into one single row and divided by (Lat1, Lat2, DistanceKm, Lon1, Lon2, DistanceMeters). How can I separate it? I have more information but it's the same pattern. As I just started learning Pandas, I do not know how to solve it.

Obs: 
    - There is a Meters into Distance;
    - How to drop km from distance?

Comment: do you need the labels in the result row? ("Lat:", "Distance: ", etc)

Comment: I need to separate. Those labels have two values.

Comment: Yeah, got that, but do you want your result to look like this: (-30.0864 30°52′57″S, -51.2245 51°18′04″W,4.8959,4895.9)?

Comment: May be like this for sure

Comment: Are the lines always formatted exactly the same way, except for the numbers (and directional letters) which change?

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using regular expressions, you can do it in the following way:

```
re.sub(r'Lat:\s+(.*)\s+Lon:\s+(.*)\s+[A-Z]\w+:\s+(.*)\s+[A-Z]\w+:\s+(.*)', '(\1, \2, \3, \4)', string)
```

[Check it out!](https://pythex.org/?regex=Lat%3A%5Cs%2B(.*)%5Cs%2BLon%3A%5Cs%2B(.*)%5Cs%2B%5BA-Z%5D%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cs%2B(.*)%5Cs%2B%5BA-Z%5D%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cs%2B(.*)&test_string=Lat%3A%20-30.0864%2030%C2%B052%E2%80%B257%E2%80%B3S%20Lon%3A%20-51.2245%2051%C2%B018%E2%80%B204%E2%80%B3W%20Distance%3A%204.8959%20km%20Meters%3A%204895.9&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

It's not clear from your question whether you've already got this in a pandas dataframe, but if you're just looking at the file, you can operate on each line in your file, either by using `map()` or an iteration.

Comment: this regex can actually be put through pandas as well using it's text functions (according to my little experience), in the end it all comes down to having no fear of regex, or trying a more manual approach

Comment: @MatheusMohr Yes! I forgot about that. I'm more used to regex than pandas, so I usually just operate on the CSV itself... which is probably more risky than it's worth.

Comment: yeah, `pandas.Series,str.extract()` will do the trick with regex to place all off those groups into different columns if it's already read in a single DataFrame column

Comment: @ALollz In this case you wouldn't want to do `str.extract()` because you need the substitution. Instead I would just apply the regex in a lambda function ` df.a.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'<the pattern>', '<replacement>', x))`

Comment: You wouldn't use the sub, you'd just use the raw string above as the `pat` argument, and the capture groups get placed into separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's a txt and there's not much to automatically handle it, you'll have to handle it fully as a text and use pandas' text functions. With that in mind, use the labels as breakpoints, in order to split your data as you need.

Considering the line you posted, an easy solution would go like this:

1. Replace "Lat: " (mind the whitespace) with nothing (""), to clear it.
2. Split the resulting line by "Lon: ". The [0] element of that split is your lat, the [1] is the rest of the line.
3. Follow that logic, splitting by the labels, to split all your data as you need it.
4. Use "replace" to clear the "km" from your distance.

As for "HOW" to actually do it, check the docs on text functions: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings